# How to realize when a browser tab has been duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, cross-browser, duplicates

I'm having problems with a duplicate tab on Chrome (session's stuff) and I'd like to avoid the action of duplicating tabs (or lacking that close the duplicate one). I'm opening the tab as it was a popup, with no address bar, no status bar, and no nothing, just the window. There's no way to duplicate a tab (opened as a popup) in IE and Firefox (at least I havent found one), but in chrome is still possible.

[I also know I'm not able to programmatically check if there's an already open duplicated tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553334/how-to-get-the-url-of-currently-opened-tabs-in-all-browsers-with-php-or-javascri)

Any idea how to approach this?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Goal**

Just to clarify: The goal is to is to detect (and close) a tab that has been opened via Chrome's "Duplicate" right-click menu option.

**First try**

The "Duplicate tab" action works almost exactly like when reloading a page after the user has clicked "Back" then "Forward", so you are basically implementing a version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button):

```
function onLoad()
{
    if ($('#myStateInput').val() === '') // Load with no state.
        $('#myStateInput').val('already loaded'); // Set state
    else
        alert("Loaded with state. (Duplicate tab or Back + Forward)");
}
```

Thats great and all, but you *only* want to detect when you "Duplicate tab". To do this we can blank out the state in `onbeforeunload`. This works because `onbeforeunload` gets only called when the user clicks "Back" or "Forward" but not when duplicating a tab.

**Second try**

```
function onLoad()
{
    if ($('#myStateInput').val() === '') // Load with no state.
        $('#myStateInput').val('already loaded'); // Set state
    else
        alert("Duplicate tab! Do something.");

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() // Back or Forward buttons
    {
        $('#myStateInput').val(''); // Blank the state out.
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @JosiahDaniels, this seems to work great with Chrome, but when I've tested it in IE10 the alert didn't appeared, do you know if there's a workaround for IE? I'll keep working, in case I solve it I will answer here, regards

Comment: @maxivis The IE duplicate button does the equivalent of copying the url, opening a new tab, and pasting. No form data is preserved. Other than really ugly hacks using cookies, I don't see a good way to handle this.

Comment: It's true what JosiahDaniels said, is like copy and paste the URL. In case anyone needs it, I solved it with cookies

Comment: You can also use [BroadcastChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231610/975097) to detect duplicate tabs.

Comment: I have a solution using BroadcastChannel here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261626/10827704

Comment: Doesn't work with modern chrome.

Answer (score 6):

My application required that a user can only sign on once so I can use the localStorage to reliably cache records.  The signon uses localStorage flags to enforce this requirement and uses the window.name to know which user owns the tab.

The issue was that the browser duplicate tab facility messed up the enforcement.  The code below forces a signon page to appear in the duplicated tab if they duplicate a signed on session.

This solution was tested in Chrome.  It makes use of the fact that a duplicated tab has no name.  **This characteristic may not exist in all browsers**.

The preventDuplicateTab function is called very early in the page load sequence.

```
/* This prevents users from duplicating the tab.  If they do it
 * triggers the start page which checks for duplicate userid
 */
function preventDuplicateTab() {
  if (sessionStorage.createTS) { 
    // Chrome at least has a blank window.name and we can use this
    // signal this is a duplicated tab.
    console.log("Existing sessionStorage "+sessionStorage.createTS+" 
               w.name="+window.name);
    if (!window.name) {
      window.name = "*ukn*";
      sessionStorage.createTS = Date.now(); // treat as new
      window.location = "/res/Frame.htm?page=start.htm"; // force to 
                                                               signon screen
    }
  } else {
    sessionStorage.createTS = Date.now();
    console.log("Create sessionStorage "+sessionStorage.createTS+" 
                                    w.name="+window.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Firefox also doesn't copy window name to the new tab.

Comment: window.name is accessible to all pages in the tab, and so we will not be able to depend on it right?

Answer (score 6):

In `onLoad` function, I used `window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]).type` for check duplicate tab in browser.

If type value is `back_forward`, that value is duplicate tab.

I share for whom concerned.

```
var navigationType = (window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0]).type;
//back_forward value is duplicate tab
if(navigationType == 'back_forward'){
    alert('Can not concurrent edit dashboard...');
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but how can i tell the original browser tab that a clone has been made of it? The original tabs navigationType is still `reload` for me

Comment: If I navigate back and then forward in the same tab, the page's onload would be triggered and we would wrongly consider the tab as duplicated right?

Answer (score 2):

Nice to see that this question has answers coming up even now. I was facing this issue as well and I solved it by the following method, but with a catch.

I depend upon [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for a Tab based storage, where I store a unique ID. Every time our page initializes, we use [Broadcast Channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) to ask the other tabs whether they have the same uniqueID. If they do, we can just refresh the Unique ID for the new tab.

You can find more details in the Repository Readme - https://github.com/haricane8133/unique-tabid

The NPM package I published is at https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-tabid, and an example of how to use this package in a React app is at https://github.com/haricane8133/unique-tabid-client.

Comment: Thank you! I am testing your package, and it is working like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and created a npm package for this use case.

It does cover most browsers and use-cases.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-tab-duplicated

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32974739)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent multiple tabs (duplicate or not), you could use a combination of the accepted answer here, and one of the solutions to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008432/1257546

I know that my solution, with local and session storage, works for me :-)

If you have to detect sessions in multiple browsers you would need a server side solution.